# Why am I getting an invalid password validation with compareHash() when calling my cloud-hosted Node.js server but not when hosting locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am a first year student working with my team to improve our last hackathon project.
We are hosting our Node.js/Express/Sequelize backend server on Render and a Postgres database on Supabase.

When a user registers on our front end, we store the hashed (bcrypt) password in our database. When the frontend makes a request to our API to login, it passes a JSON {"username":"xyz", "password":"xyz"} which is then destructured in our backend at the control layer and validated in our service layer by the following:

```
const createUserSession = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const oneUser = await User.findOne({ where: {username: username} });
    if (oneUser && oneUser.username === username && bcrypt.compareSync(password, oneUser.password)) {
      const token = await Token.create({ UserId: oneUser.id });
      await oneUser.addToken(token);
      const authToken = generateAuthToken({uuid: token.uuid});
      return {oneUser, authToken};
    }
  } catch(error) {
     throw error;
  }
}
```

When we make calls to our hosted server on Render, we get an invalid password error thrown from our service layer. However, when we host our server locally and make calls to it from our frontend, the password is validated and returns a user and authtoken as expected.

I am stumped as to why the same code behaves differently on our hosted/local servers.

So far I've tried inserting console logs for the purposes of debugging. I'm seeing in our locally hosted server's terminal that the destructured password is not distorted in any way and that after hashing the password passed as a parameter matches that in our database character for character. I don't currently have access to our hosted server's terminal as it's linked to my friend's github so I have no idea what's going on there.

From our frontend, the API call in question to our cloud server returns a 500 code with the correct payload designed to return an invalid password error. When making it to a locally hosted server, it returns 200 and our intended information.

Comment: Maybe your bcrypt's `salt` is different from local and server? Have you checked it out?

Comment: Hello! I believe our hosted server is deployed from our GitHub repo so I think they should be the same.